# Overriding Revtex's bibliographical style

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib, revtex

I have prepared a manuscript with revtex4-1 and submitted to a journal which requires a different bibliographical style. Since I only need to make this change I don't want to change to a different package altogether, so my idea was to simply override the way citation information is printed. I.e., I want to change the revtex4-1 style:

[1] M.A. Caro, J. Smith, and J. Doe. "Nice paper with very important results", Journal of Very Important Research **1**, 69 (2017).

to the following style:

[1] Caro, M.A.; Smith, J.; Doe, J. Nice paper with very important results. *Journal of Very Important Research* **2017**, *1*, 69.

Can I do this in any simple manner?

Comment: Note in case it is relevant to the answer that Miguel Caro contributed a lot more to the work than the Jonh Doe and John Smith guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no issue simply adding `\bibliographystyle`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Caro2017,
  author =    {M. A. Caro and J. Smith and J. Doe},
  title =     {Nice paper with very important results},
  journal =   {Journal of Very Important Research},
  year =      {2017},
  volume =    {1},
  pages =     {69},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

Hello world~\cite{Caro2017}.

\bibliographystyle{achemso} % Similar to the requested style
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Note that as REVTeX is specifically for submission to particular journals,it may be inappropriate for others in non-obvious ways.

---

If you did want to use `achemso` here (the style suggests you might), something like

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Caro2017,
  author =    {M. A. Caro and J. Smith and J. Doe},
  title =     {Nice paper with very important results},
  journal =   {Journal of Very Important Research},
  year =      {2017},
  volume =    {1},
  pages =     {69},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{revtex4-1}

% Special control database for achemso
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-ctrl.bib}
@Control{achemso-ctrl,
  ctrl-article-title = {yes}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\nocite{achemso-ctrl}% Sets up achemso style

Hello world~\cite{Caro2017}.

\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\bibliography{\jobname,\jobname-ctrl}

\end{document}
```

includes the control entry which turns on printing of article titles. Other `achemso` settings could also be added if required.

Comment: This seems to work, I was trying to use the `\citefield{}{}` commands which did not work. `achemso` does not print the article's title - is there an option to fix that? I am aware that revtex is for particular journals, but we usually decide where to submit the paper more or less towards the end of the writing process, so I do all the initial drafting with revtex since APS and AIP journals are my regular target journals.

Comment: @Miguel I've updated my answer to cover inclusion of titles. I'm not familiar with `\citefield`: please add some detail to the question (perhaps an example based on my one).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works! I am indeed trying to submit to an ACS journal. I will add the `\citefield` stuff when I'm done submitting this paper. I use it to manipulate citations with `beamer` presentations.